# jqplot disable autoscale for third graph

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqplot

Im working with jqplot in my project and there shouldn't be any autoscaling, so i disableed it with

`axes: {
        yaxis: {
          min: 1,
          max: 5
        },
        xaxis: {
          min: 1,
          max: 5
        }
}`

That works really good for plotting one or two arrays, but when I plot 3 it starts with autoscaling again.
Is there any option which must be enabled,too?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try setting the `autoscale` option to `false`?

Try setting the autoscale to false in `axes{}` or `xaxis`(or `yaxis`)

Check jqPLot docs : [jqPlot Autoscale Axis](http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/jqplot-core-js.html#Axis.autoscale)

Hope it helps !!

Comment: Yeah I tried that, but it doesn't work( but i just set it for all axes,not for each for itself) After a little trial-and-error I solved it by setting the yaxis, y2axis and y3axis to the min and max I want to habe (Im shure this isn't the way this should be solved)